# Is a variable created by vars.put a constant variable?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to create a variable called "ID" by assigning a timestamp, but the problem is that when I set a new value, it doesn't work. In each iteration, it seems like no matter how many times I re-create an "ID", it always refers to the first one. Does this mean that the variable created by **vars.put** is a constant variable? Or it is just the same concept with the [User Defined Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145128/variable-value-not-updated-in-each-iteration-in-jmeter)?

[Create "ID" with vars.put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxqeR.png)

[First iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVFnJ.png)

[Second iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf2cf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So either move your [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) into "Parameters" section and change your code to be

```
vars.put('ID', Parameters)
```

[image]

Or use pure Groovy to get the current timestamp:

```
vars.put('ID', System.currentTimeMillis() as String)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)